# How to prove $\tfrac{(n+1)^k}{(kn+k)....(kn+1)} = \tfrac{1}{k^k}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The last part of my calc 3 quiz doesn't make sense to me. In the answer key, my teacher simplifies

$$\dfrac{(n+1)^k}{(kn+k)....(kn+1)} = \dfrac{1}{k^k}.$$

I don't know how this is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the question is
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+1)^k}{(kn+k)\cdots(kn+1)} = \frac{1}{k^k}
$$
To do this, divide numerator and denominator by $n^k$:
$$
\frac{(n+1)^k}{(kn+k)\cdots(kn+1)} = \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^k}{(k+\frac{k}{n})\cdots(k+\frac{1}{n})}
$$
so that we see the limit is
$$
\frac{1^k}{k\cdots k} = \frac{1}{k^k}
$$